# Adding a CSS property (top) if a different CSS property (color) is present

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I am trying to add to the CSS of a div, given the presence of a different CSS property in that div using jQuery. This is the algorithm:

> If `#div1` has the property `color:red`, then add `top: -10px;` to `#div1` as well.

This is what I have tried:

```js
if ($('#div1').css('color') === 'red') {
    $("#div1").css("top","-10px");
}
```

Can anyone spot my error?

NOTE: While it would be the better option to add a CSS class that handles both `color` and `top`, I am not able to edit the stylesheet of the website.

Comment: This calls for basic debugging first. Which part doesn't work? What does `$('#div1').css('color')` return? (the `top` value is going to need `px` added  though)

Comment: Perhaps it would make more sense to add a css class that handles both `color` and `top`?

Comment: @jrummell. That would be the better option, but I was unfortunately not able to change the stylesheet of the website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no syntax error in the posted code, `css` method returns a `rgb` value:

```
if ($('#div1').css('color') === 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
```

However, instead of checking colors you can add a class to your element and use `hasClass` method:

```
.error {
   color: red;
}
```

```
if ( $('#div1').hasClass('error') ) {
```

Answer (score 3):

this is because color can be represented in many ways, eg. rgb(255,0,0), "red", #f00 etc.

Answer (score 0):

The css color will come back as rgb values.

You could do like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dseKY/)

```
if ($('#div1').css('color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {  
    $("#div1").css("color","blue");
}
```

Note I changed the output to blue for obvious change.

Not sure if it's browser dependant so I would strongly suggest you add a class to the div and check if #div1 has that class instead of checking for the color.

Answer (score -2):

not tested but the correct syntax should have a colon and curly braces

```
if ($('#div1').css('color') === 'red') {
    $("#div1").css({"top":"-10"});
}
```